# The last packet successfully received from the server was 43417 seconds ago

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

We are using Spring 4.2.5, Hibernate 4.1.4, MYSql to build REST services. We are facing very weird issue and couldn't understand what is happening exactly and getting below error:

The last packet successfully received from the server was 43417 seconds ago.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 43417 seconds ago, which  is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

To get the database connection we are using java based configuration like below:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan({ "api.configuration" })

public class HibernateConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateConfiguration.class);
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "api.domain" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true");
        dataSource.setUsername("test"); 
        dataSource.setPassword("test");
        return dataSource;
    }


    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("connection.autoReconnect",  "true");
        properties.put("connection.autoReconnectForPools","true");
        properties.put("connection.is-connection-validation-required", "true");

        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
       em.setDataSource(dataSource());
       em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "api.domain" });

       JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
       em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
       em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

       return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws PropertyVetoException{
       JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject() );
       return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
       return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Have googled out and find out we can solve this by adding below two properties:

```
<property name=”validationQuery” value=”SELECT 1″ />

<property name=”testOnBorrow” value=”true” />
```

As we are using java configuration instead of XML based, we don't know the exact property name to add for **validationQuery** and **testOnBorrow**  in java class as we have **hibernate.show_sql**

Please suggest

Answer (score 6):

The database killed its session and physical connection, but client side didn't know about that until now.

Let's first understand the problem. `java.sql.Connection` is a Java object that represents some MySQL Server connection. This is a client-server communication that happens over TCP. If server connection is broken or TCP connection was broken client side doesn't know about this, so the Java object is still there but it cannot communicate with the server any more. In your case MySQL Server kills stale connections if they are idle for some time (8 hours by default).

If you create a bare Driver Connection this situation would be very rare though - such connections are created and closed after they are used for short time. In your example things are pretty chaotic - you use both SessionFactory and EntityManagerFactory and it looks like you use bare connections (and it's hard to get this error with bare connections), so I won't comment on it..

The options that you found are not for Hibernate. They are for one of the production-ready DB Pools ([Tomcat JDBC Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) I assume). So you should use that pool (or another one like C3P0) and configure it to periodically check the connections - this way the connections will not be stale from MySQL Server perspective. Here is an example of [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:qalatraining;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="user" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3600"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

And now you should pass this DataSource to Hibernate:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

There is a lot more to configuring DB Pools, you can find details [here](https://github.com/qala-io/java-course/blob/master/docs/programme/articles/db-pools-breaking-physical-connections.md) and a working example [here](https://github.com/qala-io/java-course/blob/master/src/main/resources/dao-context.xml).